# My evolutionary ai gets random errors when I use randrange

Tags: python, machine-learning

I was running this code which is meant to be an 'ai' that learns that the answer is 10. every time I run it, it sometimes gives me this error. This is in Python 3.6.3

Error:

```
, 1)
  File "D:\Jonte\python\lib\random.py", line 198, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)
```

Code:

```
from random import randrange
# middle = randrange(0,2)  <- this is potential code
# the reason i have the question minus the answer is so that they are related in some way
# output = question - middle <- this is potential code for the middle  analysis
answer = 10
'''
reminder create a list for the first using randrange then use the method 
described
'''
correctanswers = []
# evaluation of the output to the correct answer
def cauculate_answers(i, question): #x is a list holder
    while i != 11:
        if question[i] >= 6:
            correctanswers.append(question[i])
        if question[i] == 10:
            print("right")
        else:
            print("wrong")
        i += 1
questionlist = [randrange(1, 11), randrange(1, 11), randrange(1, 11), 
randrange(1, 11), randrange(1, 11), randrange(1, 11), randrange(1, 11), 
randrange(1, 11), randrange(1, 11), randrange(1, 11), randrange(1, 11)]        
cauculate_answers(0, questionlist)
print ()
print()
print(correctanswers)
def incrementanswers(correctans):
    i = 0
    length = len(correctans)
    while i != length :
        randevalrange = answer - correctans.pop(i)
        apeendvalue = correctans[i] + randrange( randevalrange * -1, randevalrange, 1)
        correctans.append(apeendvalue)
        i = 1 + i

# run through this as long as correct answers
# each number gets minused off answer to find incremental value
# then use that with this algorithm answer-correctanswers[i]= randevalrange
# then store all of this data in a temporary dictionary
# then delete all data in correct answers then fill questionlist with
# randrange(randevalrange, -randevalrange) this repeated twice for each
# incremental value
#
x = 0
while x != 10:
    incrementanswers(correctanswers)
    print (cauculate_answers(0, correctanswers))

#if i return the succesfull questions i have to feed it a dictionary
#it wont work until you figure out the next bit
```

Comment: I skimmed the title and read "My revolutionary AI..." and marveled at the *juevos* required to make that statement. Carry on!

Comment: Sometimes I also get an IndexError... Also, once you fix _those_ errors, your `while x != 10:` loop will just run infinitely as `x` is never changed.

Answer (score 1):

First observe that `randrange` will raise `ValueError` if its second argument is not greater than the first:

```
randrange(0,0,1) # always raises ValueError
```

Next observe that you have a line of code which is isomorphic to

```
randrange(-x,x,1)
```

Then observe that if `x==0` the last line effectively becomes `randrange(0,0,1)`. My `x` is the analogue of your `randevalrange`.

In summary, make sure that `randevalrange` can never be `0`.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Jonte\python\tcl\again\nueral_net.py", line 52, in <module>
    incrementanswers(correctanswers)
  File "D:\Jonte\python\tcl\again\nueral_net.py", line 39, in incrementanswers
    apeendvalue = correctans[i] + randrange( randevalrange * -1, randevalrange, 1)
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: wait sorry i have figured it out

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, you might upvote and/or accept it.